# Drupal 6: Blank pages at Ads Module Settings

Tags: drupal, module, drupal-6, administration

I uploaded and activated [Ads Module](http://drupal.org/project/ad) with no error. I can see Ads-List pages.

> List  |  Remote ads  |  Reports  | 
>   Settings  |  Ad groups  |  Channels

but all other pages are blank

What can be the problem?

Comment: This looks like a WSOD due to a php error - check your Drupal log and webserver/php error logs for hints on the culprit.

Comment: Check how much memory your site running. The default php install is too low on most *nix servers.

Comment: Also, make sure you have no ad-blocker running. I've had this same problem because firefox blocked the entire edit page in its adblocker.

Answer (score 0):

Did you clear the caches on the server already? Are you running Varnish or any other reverse-proxy / static cache that needs to be cleared?

What happens when you disable and uninstall the module, then clear all the caches?

What do your PHP, Apache and MySQL error logs say?

If clearing the caches doesn't doesn't do the trick:

1) Check the thenameoftheadmodule.module file and search for _menu (or thenameoftheadmodule_menu).

2) Check what's the status of the callback paths found in the menu hook inside the menu router table.

3) Debug each menu hook entry (or the one that doesn't work) and the debugger will tell you what's wrong.